How to toggle dark mode in ionic8 Angular 18
I have three CSS styles in my global.scss file. Currently, I am using dark mode, but I want to change them conditionally. How can I do this in Ionic 8 and Angular 18?
Here is my global.scss code.
// @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.always.css";
// @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.class.css";
@import '@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.system.css';

I want to add one toggle button in my app so i can witch theme according to that.

I do stuff like that with css variables like this

This question is similar to: Angular Ionic dark mode toggle. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SwissCodeMen it's not a similar question in ionic 8 and angular 18 there is no theme/variable.scss file and I want to use default mode which is already available in global.scss

I find the solution for ionic 8 and angular 18.
// @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.always.css";
@import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.class.css"; // uncomment this
// @import '@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.system.css'; // comment this

And toggle the class
document.documentElement.classList.toggle('ion-palette-dark', theme === 'dark');

Here is my full code which i implemented
constructor(){
  this.initializeTheme();
}

initializeTheme() {
  let currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

  if (!currentTheme) {
    // Default to dark theme if no theme is set
    currentTheme = 'dark';
    localStorage.setItem('theme', currentTheme);
  }

  this.applyTheme(currentTheme);
}

toggleTheme() {
  const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'dark';
  const newTheme = currentTheme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';

  this.applyTheme(newTheme);
  localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
}

applyTheme(theme: string) {
  // Update theme and toggle the class
  this.theme = theme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light';
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('ion-palette-dark', theme === 'dark');
}

Here is my hrml for toggle dark and light theme
<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
  <ion-item lines="none" detail="false" (click)="toggleTheme()">
    <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" slot="start" [name]="theme === 'dark' ? 'sunny' : 'moon'"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>{{ theme === 'dark' ? 'Light': 'Dark' }} Mode</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-menu-toggle>


To make it conditional make below mentioned changes:
1).  comment all thee of these in your global.scss:
// @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.always.css";
// @import "@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.class.css";
// @import '@ionic/angular/css/palettes/dark.system.css';

2). Go to your theme/variable.scss
Take everything out of @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) media query and pase it out side (simply comment media query open and close tag).
3). On the basis of your condition you can toggle dark mode on and off:
changeDarkMode(darkodetype: boolean){
   document.body.classList.toggle('dark', darkModetype);
}

Note: Disableing dark mode media query will always shows light mode. you have to enable dark mode programatically.

I want to use the default Ionic dark and light modes that are already available in the global.scss file and there is no option of theme/variable.scss in ionic 8 and angular 18.
